# Calculate the radius in meters using mapkit

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I need to know the distance (in kilometers) from center map to the other side of the screen,  (and if the zoom change the distance will change).

I need to implement this feature in this function

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
}
```

Any ideas how i can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 18):

MkMapView has properties named centerCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D) and region (MKCoordinateRegion). Region is a struct that:

```
typedef struct {
    CLLocationDegrees latitudeDelta;
    CLLocationDegrees longitudeDelta;
}MKCoordinateSpan
```

You should be able to create another point, based on centerCoordinate, let's say, by adding latitudeDelta to you latitude property or centerCoordinate, and calculate distance using the method of CLLocation:

```
- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location
```

Something like this

```
MkMapView * mapView; // init somewhere
MKCoordinateRegion region = mapView.region;
CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate = mapView.centerCoordinate;
CLLocation * newLocation = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:centerCoordinate.latitude+region.span.latitudeDelta longitude:centerCoordinate.longitude] autorelease];
CLLocation * centerLocation = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:centerCoordinate.latitude:longitude:centerCoordinate.longitude] autorelease];
CLLocationDistance distance = [centerLocation distanceFromLocation:newLocation]; // in meters
```

And just calculate each time a delegate fires a certain method (decide which you need: MKMapViewDelegate)

Comment: `centerCoordinate.latitude+region.span.latitudeDelta` has to be `centerCoordinate.latitude+region.span.latitudeDelta/2` to get correct radius.

Answer (score 3):

Because rectangles aren't circles you can't get a radius.

But you can still get the furthest distance from the center of a region.
Reusing the same idea as above but embeded in a swift extension.

```
extension MKCoordinateRegion {
    func distanceMax() -> CLLocationDistance {
        let furthest = CLLocation(latitude: center.latitude + (span.latitudeDelta/2),
                             longitude: center.longitude + (span.longitudeDelta/2))
        let centerLoc = CLLocation(latitude: center.latitude, longitude: center.longitude)
        return centerLoc.distanceFromLocation(furthest)
    }
}
```

Usage

```
let radius = mapView.region.distanceMax()
```